# Anyone can optimize this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Database server is Microsoft SQL Server, but I don't have Administrator access to it.
So, I don't know which version, and I don't know which indexes exist.

To access the database, I am using ADO.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
-- Get master objid and order_number and activity time
SELECT A.objid,
       A.order_number,
       F.entry_time
-- From these tables
FROM   dbo.table_master as A,
       dbo.table_activity as F
-- link of the tables
WHERE  F.objid = A.objid
       -- Retrieve code = 1900 only
       AND F.code = 1900
       -- Which have info like this:
       AND F.info LIKE '%to SUPPORT.'
       -- And entry time between these times:
       AND F.entry_time >= '2011-10-01 00:00:00'
       AND F.entry_time <= '2011-12-05 23:59:59'
-- We want the earliest entry (because there might be multiple code = 900 and info like)
ORDER  by F.entry_time
```

Is it possible to optimize this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it particularly slow?  Can you show the query plan?  Also, what flavor of SQL is this (SQL Server, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the database from SSMS?

Comment: @jadarnel27: OP said that this is SQLServer.

Comment: The LIKE will kill your performance since it is applied to anything found.  Is there anyway to avoid it?  Also, best way to optimize a query is to provide a complete index for that query, which is to say, an index by code, info, and entry_time.

Comment: @Neil - It depends how many rows are brought back by the rest of the query. If the predicate on `code,entry_time` is sufficiently selective then this residual predicate might not be too bad. Don't think this question is really answerable as it stands as not enough information.

Comment: @MarkB My mistake, I was looking at the tags (it didn't have sql-server when I commented), and forgot OP had mentioned that at the beginning of the question.

Comment: If you can create a computed column and add an index ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)) on the column it would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are things you could do differently:

- use `RIGHT(f.info, 11) = 'to SUPPORT.'` instead of `F.info LIKE '%to SUPPORT.'`
- use an `INNER JOIN` as @xQbert suggested
- use `BETWEEN` for the date range instead of the combination of `<` and `>`.

In my testing, the only one that made a difference in performance was the first option.  All 3 items will generate the same execution plan, however, the `RIGHT` function was around 10x quicker in my test in terms of actual execution time.  I'm using `STATISTICS TIME` to test.

If possible, I would try to get access to look at the indexes.  Having the tables properly indexed will make a way bigger difference than the `RIGHT` function.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I read from other users that my query is difficult to optimize because not much info (indexes?), but I think your RIGHT() might help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, the worst part of your query and also the part that cannot be easily optimized, is

```
AND F.info LIKE '%to SUPPORT.'
```

because the indexes work only for matching from the start of the string, not from the end.

so if you want better performance, you probably need to find some way to work around this.

(oh. just realized it's not MySQL. this answer would be 100% correct for mysql, but i expect it to be correct for most of common database engines)

Comment: It is the case for all indexes.  If you consider an index to be ordered (be it as a list or a tree it does not matter), the last character only matters where all preceding characters match with another item.  In essense, the order of the items, form the perspective of the tail of this string, is virtually random.  This means that the index is useless, and the entire table is scanned.

Comment: but as far as i know you can create an index that is reversed and look for the string reversed. This is used in exactly these cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different way of writing the same thing; it may yield faster performance
due to the nature of the join and the use of between.  It also puts limits on the join criteria which force evaluation before the %to so your working with a smaller subset when the %to SUPPORT is evaluated.

```
SELECT A.objid, A.order_number, F.entry_time 
FROM dbo.table_master as A
INNER JOIN dbo.table_activity as F 
  ON F.objid = A.objid
  AND F.code = 1900
  AND F.entry_time BETWEEN '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-05 23:59:59'
WHERE 
F.info LIKE '%to SUPPORT.'
ORDER by F.entry_time
```

EDITED After 1st comment.

Comment: Neither of the changes you make will affect performance at all.

Comment: This is also improved a bit on the performance. I changed the LIKE to use RIGHT (). Thanks!